# Not adding documents to CloudSearch domain

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I'm playing around with the imdb example of CloudSearch and so far I could search but not add.

This returns success but once I want to query the data, there are no results:

> curl  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:
>   application/json" -X POST
>   http://doc-imdbtest-bs4t3cjarozs76ll2iv4xi.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/documents/batch
>   -d "[{ \"type\": \"add\",\"id\":   \"tt0484562\",\"version\": 1,\"lang\": \"en\",\"fields\": {\"title\": \"asdfasdf: The Dark Is
>   Rising\",\"director\": \"Cunningham, David L.\",\"genre\":
>   [\"Adventure\",\"Drama\",\"Fantasy\",\"Thriller\"],\"actor\":
>   [\"McShane, Ian\",\"Eccleston, Christopher\",\"Conroy,
>   Frances\",\"Crewson, Wendy\",\"Ludwig, Alexander\",\"Cosmo,
>   James\",\"Warner, Amelia\",\"Hickey, John Benjamin\",\"Piddock,
>   Jim\",\"Lockhart, Emma\"]}}]"
>   {"status": "success", "adds": 1, "deletes": 0}

Anyone could have an idea why this happens? 
Supposedly I got all the due permissions, so I'd expect some sort of delay.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody ran indexing on the documents, CloudSearch may return an empty result set till the  indexing is complete if you happen to search on data being indexed. Try again after a while and it should work. ( Also make sure the query is alright . )